# Late payments due to online banking not working

Tags: credit

Last year I opened a new bank account and got a credit card with the same bank. Online banking hasn’t been working since the beginning, so I cannot pay my credit card balance online, check the outstanding balance and set automatic payments.

This resulted in two late payments.

1. first time, I wrote a check to the bank to pay out all the credit card balance. It turned out that the check was never cashed and that was reported as a late payment (25$).
2. second time, I went to the bank and made a payment from my bank account. I requested a receipt of the payment. After that, I have been out of the country and haven’t used the credit card. I got an email from the bank telling me that I had 49$ to pay. Most likely, it was some expense that was still pending when I requested to pay all the balance. Online banking was still not working and it resulted in a second late payment. I then wired the remaining 49$ to the bank.

In both cases I tried in good faith to pay (and I had the money to pay). Is there something I can do to have the late payments removed from my credit reports? They are the only 2 spots on an otherwise clean credit history, and it is quite frustrating since in both cases I wanted to pay but could not because I couldn’t login to online banking.

I have emails to the bank in which I was complaining about the issue , and emails with the customer service trying (unsuccessfully) so solve the login problem).

Comment: Neither of your two instances have anything to do with online banking. It's hard to tell what exactly the problem is. Anytime I setup a new payment scheme, I test it long before any payment is due, and verify that the payment is received in a timely fashion before I start trusting it to make my automatic payments on time. It's not clear from your question if the bank you are paying is the one that actually issued you the card, or if you are having the bank make payments to you card servicer on your behalf.

Comment: What kind of bank is that?

Answer (score 0):

Paying the billed amount only includes charges up to the time the bill was computed. If there was another charge made after that, it could account for the $45. Unfortunate but not very surprising. Explicitly saying that you wanted to pay the entire balance rather than the balance due might have prevented this glitch, assuming the additional charge had been posted at that time.

Mailed check never being cashed... might never have arrived, might have gotten misfiled. That happens sometimes. If you have a good record otherwise, you may be able to get them to skip the late payment fee; you're probably still on the hook for the interest unless they are feeling particularly generous.

Two instances isn't going to do much to your credit rating that reliably paying won't wipe out. And unless you are about to sign a lease or take out a loan or are jobhunting, your credit rating is mostly irrelevant. I wouldn't worry about it; just try to keep this from happening again.

Unfortunately, online banking is a convenience, not a guaranteed service. Outages and configuration issues do happen. Which is one reason I still get paper statements; that gives me a fallback if online is down. (Assuming the post office works, which it usually does.)

Comment: ‘Explicitly saying that you wanted to pay the entire balance rather than the balance due might have prevented this glitch, assuming the additional charge had been posted at that time.‘ Actually, I did ask to pay the entire balance.

Comment: Late fees are not a big problem, and interest was probably a few dollars. It’s just frustrating that I have late payments on my reports. Do I have chances to have the late payments forgiven and removed the reports? I paid in full as soon as I came to know about it, and I don’t owe any money to that bank.

Comment: “ And unless you are about to sign a lease or take out a loan or are jobhunting, your credit rating is mostly irrelevant.” I am relocating so I want to buy a house, that’s also why I care about my credit score.

Comment: If the online banking isn't working, change banks. I incurred two late fees last year because US snail mail is worse than ever. Yeh, maintaining an unblemished record means something to me but throwing away two $25 late fees really rubbed me wrong.  Because I could demonstrate that my bank mailed the payments in a timely fashion, they were waived. And apart from this, credit cards have their own web sites where frequently, you can pay them directly from your account.